# String insertion problem in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, string

I am trying to insert a string at a position for C# string, its failing

here is the snippet.

```
  if(strCellContent.Contains("<"))
   {
         int pos = strCellContent.IndexOf("<");
         strCellContent.Insert(pos,"&lt;");
   }
```

please tell me the solution

Comment: And would you be as kind to explain how it's failing?

Comment: First thing, you should clear that you want to insert new string by replacing "<" or concatenate new string without replacing <

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value contains the new string that you desire.

```
strCellContent = strCellContent.Insert(pos,"&lt;");
```

Answer (score 7):

Gunner and Rhapsody have given correct changes, but it's worth knowing *why* your original attempt failed. The String type is immutable - once you've got a string, you can't change its contents. All the methods which *look* like they're changing it *actually* just return a new value. So for example, if you have:

```
string x = "foo";
string y = x.Replace("o", "e");
```

the string `x` refers to will still contain the characters "foo"... but the string `y` refers to will contain the characters "fee".

This affects all uses of strings, not just the particular situation you're looking at now (which would definitely be better handled using `Replace`, or even better still a library call which knows how to do all the escaping you need).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be better of with a `Replace` instead of an `Insert`:

```
strCellContent = strCellContent.Replace("<", "&lt;");
```

Maybe doing `Server.HtmlEncode()` is even better:

```
strCellContent = Server.HtmlEncode(strCellContent);
```

Comment: +1. Manual search/replace is a terrible idea in face of something like `HtmlEncode` (assuming he has the ability to call that).  The Xml library also has similar auto-escaping features.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at your code I think you want to do a replace, but try this:

```
 if(strCellContent.Contains("<"))    
 {
      int pos = strCellContent.IndexOf("<");
      strCellContent = strCellContent.Insert(pos,"&lt;");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Contains` is not a good idea here, because you need to know the position. This solution will be more efficient.

```
int pos = strCellContent.IndexOf("<");
if (pos >= 0)   //that means the string Contains("<")
{
   strCellContent = strCellContent.Insert(pos,"&lt;");  //string is immutable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained with the code, I will add that

> The value of the String object is the
>   content of the sequential collection,
>   and that value is **immutable** (that is,
>   it is read-only). 
>   For more information about the immutability of strings, see the [Immutability and the  StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx#Immutability) Class section.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx